# How to determine fundamental frequencies (beats/minute) of heartbeat? (matlab)

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, autocorrelation

```
read = matfile('ECG.mat');
[cor, lags] = xcorr(read.ecg, read.ecg);
read.Fs;
```

So i have `read.ecg` (signal) and `read.Fs`. How can i find/count beats/minute in matlab?

Here is plot

[image: corr plot]

Comment: what is the scaling of the $\tau$-axis?  is it seconds, milliseconds?  sample periods?  if the latter, what is the sample rate?

can you show the same autocorrelation plot and zoom in close to the $\tau=0$ area?

Comment: look at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest processing the ECG signal through a standard QRS detection algorithm (e.g. Pan-Tompkins). Once you have isolated the QRS complexes in your ECG signal, you can simply count them, divide by the duration of your ECG signal, and convert to beats/min. Here is one implementation of Pan-Tompkins: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45840-complete-pan-tompkins-implementation-ecg-qrs-detector. I am sure you can find others on physionet.